# How can I expand a multi-customer system to handle multiple "identical" controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, scalability, controllers

**Facts:**
I'm using `webapi` on my application.
My application is a multi-customer application.
Most of my business logic is identical but I do have some differences between some customers.
The example I'll give here is a basic "login" example. I have some more critical places in my system where I need an extra controller(I know that I can perform multiple workarounds with this simple login controller).

Let's assume I have a login controller that looks something like this:

```
public class LoginController
{
   public LoginResponse Post(LoginRequest request)
   {
      // call ICustomer service to authenticate and return a response
   }
}
```

Now I use IOC for my services. So each customer can typically use a different service and authenticate differently, but what happens when I need to return different data back to the client(per customer)?

I can use `ILoginResponse` & `ILoginRequest` and achieve this using IOC, but I still would like to add another `LoginController`(with the same name so my client's will call `api\Login`) and gain another level of abstraction.

So my next thought was keep the same controller name and split each customers controller into a different DLLs.

So I would have something like this:

```
CommonControllers.dll
Customer1Controllers.dll
Customer2Controllers.dll
```

But how can I do the mapping here?

I'll have an interface that looks like:

```
public interface ILoginControllerInterface<S,T>
{
   S Post(T model);
}
```

And implementations that look like:

**CommonControllers.dll**

```
public class LoginController : ILoginControllerInterface<LoginResponse,LoginRequest>
{
   public LoginResponse Post(LoginRequest request)
   {
      // call ICustomer service to authenticate and return a response
   }
}
```

**Customer1Controllers.dll**

```
public class LoginController : ILoginControllerInterface<LoginCusomterResponse,LoginCustomerRequest>
{
   public LoginCusomterResponse Post(LoginCustomerRequest request)
   {
      // call ICustomer service to authenticate and return a response
   }
}
```

But how can I tell my resolver to resolve the "correct" LoginController?
I'm using `Unity`as my IOC container and my services are registered via configuration.
I'd like a place to register my controllers.

I've overridden the default web-api resolver using my own resolver:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

I'm using my customer resolve to resolve basically everything in my application.
I'm **not** using a controller factory. Since my resolver resolves my controllers and performs DI for me.

**Bottom line:**
If I get a request to `api/login`, how can I resolve the **correct** controller?
Lets say for customer1 I'd like to get the `Customer1Controller.dll` version and for customer2 I'd like to get the CommonControllers.dll.
I want this to be via a configuration so I can gain flexibility.

**BTW:**
If there is a better practice to do these kind of things I'd be more than glad to here about it.

**Thanks!!!**